# Which political opinions are tolerated in the 'This is Fine' chatroom?

Tags: discussion

I got banned from chat for thoughtcrime. Would it help if we codified which political opinions are acceptable in 'This is fine' and which are not?

Comment: I feel there is missing context here as seeing roughly where the "ban" might have happened, there is a [post from murgatroid99 shortly after the deleted post saying](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53879902#53879902) *"don't advocate for violence in here, especially murder, especially mass murder"* which to me, really changes the context of this question

Comment: To be perfectly clear, my quoted comment was in fact directly in response to the now-deleted comment in question.

Comment: I honestly think that not directly stating what the comment in question said is creating ambiguity and doing more harm than good. If any site mod in question disagrees and deletes this comment, I understand. The comment in question advocated rounding up large groups of people, concentrating them in camps, and then killing them. That is far beyond a "political opinion" and is wholly unacceptable here.

Answer (score 4):

I was not the moderator who issued the ban, however I do agree with it. You were not chat banned for thought-crime, you were chat banned for saying something extremely offensive which violated the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct). If you disagree with the chat ban, please use the contact link to escalate to CM's.

Comment: Can I ask which of my posts you decided to claim was "extremely offensive"?

Comment: @Studoku-ReinstateMonica If I'm not mistaken, the message in question can be viewed [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/53879764/history).